# What's up duck?

Tags: support

Just seen today that there is now a duck icon in the bottom right of the main page. I'm guessing it's a new feature but I haven't seen any announcements around it.

Can I ask what it is for? Is it the Workplace's answer to Clippy?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quack-overflow

Comment: What the duck? .

Comment: This is an April Fool's Day joke, described in [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308564/stack-exchange-has-been-taken-over-by-a-rubber-duck).

Answer (score 6):

This is an April Fool's Day joke, described in [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308564/stack-exchange-has-been-taken-over-by-a-rubber-duck). It encourages you to use the Rubber Duck method of debugging:

> A rubber duck in use by a developer to aid code review In software engineering, rubber duck debugging or rubber ducking is a method of debugging code. The name is a reference to a story in the book The Pragmatic Programmer in which a programmer would carry around a rubber duck and debug their code by forcing themselves to explain it, line-by-line, to the duck.

Comment: Ahh..makes sense I guess.. a little early though!

Comment: @motosubatsu - that's the joke! Ducks don't use calendars!

Comment: @motosubatsu special dates on SE (whether they're related to hats, April 1, or whatever) last as long as it's that date anywhere in the world, so April 1 starts early for most of us.

Comment: @MonicaCellio ahh of course.. I always forget about the whole timezone thing! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** an April fools joke.  It is a feature that a special secret group from the SE team are working on.  It was unintentionally released in the latest production build and the team is having difficulty rolling back the change.  From the rumors I have heard the team believes it should be fully tested and ready to back out the Duck feature, except for special beta users, by Tuesday.

It is important that you not try to reverse engineer the technology.  They caught me doing it and slapped an injunction on me... I hope this answer doesn't violate that.